# Where to find the server data files for maps in Linux

Tags: azerothcore

As the title saying, I couldn't find the server data files.
I want to switch my server from win10 to Linux.
I did the compile step by step follow the AC WIKI.
When doing the "Extractors", I can not find these files which necessary.
In last sthe core installation , this is the command I use:

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/azeroth-server/ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -DWITH_WARNINGS=1 -DTOOLS=0 -DSCRIPTS=static
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-DTOOLS=0` means it will NOT compile the extractors. You can either:

A) use `-DTOOLS=1` to compile and generate the extractors and then extract the  data files yourself

B) (easier) just download them

Check this page for more details: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/server-setup

Comment: so , is it possible that I could used the data files what extracted in Win10 when I run a server in Linux?

Comment: @Polupoly yes, once extracted they work on all operating systems. The only thing you should pay attention to is the version. For example, you cannot use old data files on a newer AC version because at some point they change in format and contents. Just follow the guide and you'll be fine.